# Android: ViewModel. Failed to call observer method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I'm using new arch. components from google.

I have in Activity Login/Registering Fragments that are managed thanks to `FragmentTransaction`

`Activity->RegisterFragment (with ViewPager) -> RegistrationSteps (adapter)`

Inside RegisterFragment I have ViewPager.
I want that all pages inside `ViewPager` will use the same ViewModel.

Those are registration steps (`RegistrationStepFragment`) that takes parent `RegistrationFragment` **LifecycleOwner** that scoped **ViewModel** to it- I just wanted ViewModel to be scoped to this parent Fragment.

**RegistrationFragment.class** inhered from

```
public interface FragmentViewPagerListener<T extends LifecycleFragment> {
    void nextPage();
    T getLifecycleFragment();
}
```

**RegistartionSteps (pages) inhered from**

```
public abstract class RegisterStepFragment extends LifecycleFragment {
    protected FragmentViewPagerListener mListener;
    protected RegisterViewModel mViewModel;

    public void setListener(FragmentViewPagerListener fragmentViewPagerListener) {
        this.mListener = fragmentViewPagerListener;
    }

    protected abstract void observeViewModel();

    @Override
    public void onCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(mListener.getLifecycleFragment()).get(RegisterViewModel.class);
        observeViewModel();
    }

    protected abstract boolean validateData();
}
```

All goes well until I reach 3 page, and I want to move back (to second page) Then is thrown exception in `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1)` (page 2: index: 1)

```
*java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
                                                                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.invokeCallback(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:79)
                                                                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.invokeMethodsForEvent(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:53)
                                                                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.invokeCallbacks(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:61)
                                                                      at android.arch.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:45)
                                                                      at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:209)
                                                                      at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:102)
                                                                      at android.arch.lifecycle.Li*fecycleDispatcher.dispatchIfLifecycleOwner(LifecycleDispatcher.java:150)
```

**EDIT**

Ok, I've found out that when moving to previous page, Fragment was reCreated calling and `mViewModel.observable()` received previously ***SUCCESS*** message and caused viewpager to move forward, that causes to destroy just created fragment what was causing error.

Solution is to create [SingleEventLiveData](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) that emits values only when post is called (don't notify observer if value changed before observer attached)

I mark it as CLOSE